# When is error message "Disconnected or Canceled" throw?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

In LWC, when getting record data in an interval of 500ms by the Apex method, I received an error:
`{"status":500,"body":{"message":"Disconnected or Canceled"},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Server Error","errorType":"fetchResponse"}`

It seems a Salesforce error. I did not find anywhere that throws this error in code logic.

Do you know when it happens? and what happens after the error is thrown?

Note:

- The record data was being updated in another process
- After the error is thrown, does not have any apex calls more. If I catch this error and manually call it again, the page is refreshed.
- Issue happens in the Salesforce app on iOS

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug logs on the org for the user that is accessing the LWC's page and looked for any exceptions or errors happening when you see this error on the front end?

Comment: @PhilW Yes, I have tried but I did not see any exceptions related to this error message

Comment: I logged a Salesforce issue for this (Case number #43551422)

Comment: @totaki did you got to know the reason for this error ?
I am running into this issue randomly when connecting from lwc to Apex controller